# Change permission level for groups programmatically in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to loop through all  the sites in a site collection and change the permission for a certain site.

My code is:

```
        SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;
        foreach (SPWeb web in collWebsite)
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            if (web.Name == "SiteName")
            {
                web.BreakRoleInheritance(true);

                string[] groups = new string[2] { "Group1", "Group2" };

                foreach (string item in groups)
                {
                    SPGroup removeGroup = web.SiteGroups[item];
                    web.RoleAssignments.Remove(removeGroup);

                    SPGroup addGroup = web.SiteGroups[item];
                    SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions["Read"];
                    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(addGroup);
                    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
                    web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
                }
            }

        }
```

but it gives me an error

```
Error changing permissions, details: There are uncommitted changes on the SPWeb object, call SPWeb.Update() to commit the changes before calling this method.
```

The code works just fine if I want to do the same but for lists instead

```
            SPListCollection collList = web.Lists;

            foreach (SPList oList in collList)
            {
                //and so on
```

I have tried to put web.Update() in various places but without success. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I commented out most of the stuff and only left

```
        if (web.Name == "SiteName")
        {
            web.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
            web.Update();
        }
```

but it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to do an `SPWeb.Update` and then

```
using(var newWeb = site.OpenWeb(web.ID))
{
    web.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
    web.Update();
}
```

Also, don't forget to do a `SPWeb.Dispose` on all the `AllWebs` opened in the foreach-loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this code in a Feature, then make sure that you use a Web level feature. Don't loop through AllWebs in a Site level feature.

Change the feature scope to Web and try the below code

```
using (SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web)
{
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    web.BreakRoleInheritance(true);

    string[] groups = new string[2] { "Group1", "Group2" };

    foreach (string item in groups)
    {
        SPGroup removeGroup = web.SiteGroups[item];
        web.RoleAssignments.Remove(removeGroup);

        SPGroup addGroup = web.SiteGroups[item];
        SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions["Read"];
        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(addGroup);
        roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
        web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    }
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```

Activate this feature in the required website to apply the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is.
But it could happen that the DLL is not being updated. It happened to me several times.
Try to delete the DLL from x:/windows/assembly and then redeploy the solution to see if there is any change on the behaviour.
Also try to commit the changes before this (I'm sure you already tried it out)

Regards,

Pedro